# Loading Java ImageIcon with Image Served by PHP Script

Tags: java, php, url

I need to create an ImageIcon from an image on a remote server.  When I loaded it with a URL like `http://www.server.com/1.png` it worked fine.

But recently the server was changed so that the images are stored outside of web root and must be accessed with something like `http://www.server.com/get_image.php?id=1`, where get_image.php outputs the correct headers to serve the image.  When I create an ImageIcon with that type of URL, it fails to load without throwing any exceptions and getImageLoadStatus() returns MediaTracker.ERRORED.  The image serving script works fine from a browser.

Any ideas on how could I make this work?

Thanks.

Edit: Here's the Java code.

`ImageIcon labelIcon = new ImageIcon(new URL(IMAGE_URL));

System.out.println(labelIcon.getImageLoadStatus());`

I also tried the following, but it didn't work either.

`ImageIcon labelIcon = new ImageIcon();

BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new URL(IMAGE_URL));

labelIcon.setImage(image);`

Edit: Here's the code from get_image.php.  $DB is an object included from global.php that is used to interact with a MySQL database.  I've verified that the MIME type being returned is image/png.

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['uid']))
    {
        require_once('./include/global.php');       
        getUpload(intval($_GET['uid']));
    }

    function getUpload($id)
    {
        global $DB;

        $query = "SELECT `name`, `mime_type` FROM `uploads` WHERE `id` = " . $id . " LIMIT 1";
        $arrUpload = $DB->getSingleRecord($query);

        if (count($arrUpload) > 0)
        {
            $file = UPLOADS_ROOT . $arrUpload['name'];
            header("Content-type: " . $arrUpload['mime_type']);
            header("Content-Disposition: filename=" . $arrUpload['name']);
            readfile($file);
        }
        else
        {
            header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
        }
        die();
    }
?>
```

Comment: Paste an example code snippet?

Comment: Do you have control over the source of `get_image.php`?

Comment: Run Fiddler and compare the responses from the static images and the PHP script.

Comment: Yes, I have control over get_image.php

Comment: Post the relevant snippet of it. It's likely wrong. This should be turned into a PHP problem/question. Don't forget to follow SLaks' advice to compare the headers. If you stucks, post them here as well.

Comment: I've never used Fiddler but I'm looking at it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the reasons that `ImageIcon(URL)` may fail is that the response didn't return status 200. Ensure that the URL didn't returned a redirect (status 301/302) or so. Also ensure that the request parameter name is correct. You used `id` in URL, but the PHP script expects `uid`.

To play a bit around yourself just to check what response headers the Java code actually gets, try this one:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.server.com/get_image.php?id=1");
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
for (Entry<String, List<String>> header : connection.getHeaderFields().entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(header.getKey() + "=" + header.getValue());            
}
```

Comment: The id/uid mismatch was just a posting error.  The code you provided indicates null=[HTTP/1.1 200 OK].  I'll try setting it to 200 explicitly in PHP.

Comment: Got it! Changing the header functions in the PHP to explicity return the 200 code as you suggested fixed the problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The server may be returning the wrong content type: make sure that its properly setting the content-type header to `image/png` on the response.